# Spark - 2.0: Connection Refused

Tags: apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

I'm trying to upgrade from Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.0 on EMR. (Cluster mode)

I'm getting following error while running my workload:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1672)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:270)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
>   Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in
>   awaitResult   at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
>     at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
>     at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to
>   /172.x.x.x:33190  at
>   org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
>     at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
>     at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /172.31.32.131:33190
>     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
>     ... 1 more

Note that, IP mentioned below is the IP of worker machine and this failure occurs while executing 'sortByKey'  step.

I have verified that I'm able to ssh from Master to Worker and vice-versa.

Update:

Some more info, Yarn node manager logs:

> Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:  2016-10-17 06:27:43,468
>   INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainersLauncher #66):      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545) 2016-10-17
>   06:27:43,468 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainersLauncher #66):      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456) 2016-10-17
>   06:27:43,468 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainersLauncher #66):      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execut
>   e(Shell.java:722) 2016-10-17 06:27:43,468 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainersLauncher #66):      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContain
>   erExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
>   2016-10-17 06:27:43,468 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainersLauncher #66):      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanag
>   er.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302) 2016-10-17
>   06:27:43,468 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainersLauncher #66):      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanag
>   er.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82) 2016-10-17
>   06:27:43,468 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainersLauncher #66):      at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 2016-10-17
>   06:27:43,468 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainersLauncher #66):      at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Thread
>   PoolExecutor.java:1142) 2016-10-17 06:27:43,468 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainersLauncher #66):      at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Threa
>   dPoolExecutor.java:617) 2016-10-17 06:27:43,468 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor
>   (ContainersLauncher #66):      at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I guess this occurs because of Connection refused error in worker. Also, I'm not quite sure why worker is trying to connect to itself with an IP rather than 127.0.0.1.

Comment: what version of EMR are you using? can we see a sample of the application you're running?

Comment: EMR - 5.0.0 . In my application, I'm just calling rdd.sample, followed by sortByKey, followed by collect. This exception occurs while calling sortByKey. Note that, same application works fine on EMR  4.7.2 with Spark 1.6 and I have made no change other than change in dependencies (Spark 1.6 -> Spark 2.0)

Comment: spark 5.0 has a different constructor now, so you'd need to be using `sparksession`, and accessing the rdd through that. are you using the new `sparksession` object? if that is indeed the case, we'd see it immediately if you had shared your code. please add your code to the question. :)

Comment: @Kristian: I'm still using JavaSparkContext, does SparkContext no longer works ? I will try using SparkSession to see if it helps.